# HDMI-DVI cable works on some monitors but doesn't on others

Tags: display, hdmi, dvi

I bought a HDMI to DVI-D cable today and it doesn't work on one tested monitor, but works on another. It's a High Speed HDMI cable with Ethernet.

I know there are multiple HDMI standards, perhaps also multiple DVI standards, and so I'm wondering what might be causing the problem. Could this be a HDMI/DVI version incompatibility between my laptop (providing the HDMI signal) and the monitor (receiving DVI-D signal)? Is there any way for me to debug it?

My video card is a Nvidia GeForce GT 630M, the monitor the cable does NOT work on is a Gateway LP2207, and the monitor the cable DOES work on is a Dell U2711. The Dell is a newer monitor.

All the best.

Comment: The problem is most likely about Dual-Link DVI, because HDMI is only ever single-link.

Answer (score 0):

There are two DVI standards there is DVI-I which is an analogue connection and there is DVI-D which is digital. HDMI being digital can be easily converted into DVI-D but not DVI-I. The gateway being the older monitor probably uses DVI-I and the dell probably uses DVI-D.

Ok, that is super confusing. Your older monitor supports analogue and your newer supports digital. The converter is digital therefore it wont work with the gateway as it is analogue.

Comment: lol im still finding that hard to understand hopefully it makes sense to you.

Comment: According to the manual - https://panam.gateway.com/s/Manuals/Monitors/8512837.pdf - the Gateway is DVI-I... though it also has HDMI, which would seem to be the simplest workaround.

Comment: @Tetsujin, according to the manual, it's DVI-D, so I'm guessing the issue is something else.  Interesting, though, that in trying to locate specs or a manual, I had a very hard time finding either, but Google is filled with references to the monitor regarding problems and defects.  Maybe the issue is that this monitor is among the problem units.  Your idea of connecting HDMI to HDMI directly with a cable--who'd a thunk it?  :-)

Comment: @fixer1234 - ugh, my bad, I meant DVI-D [brain fade] but yeah, straight through HDMI->HDMI would kind of avoid the issue ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin The gateway doesnt have HDMI does it?? The only "specs" i found said that it had a DVI of some sort and a VGA no HDMI?

Comment: It's DVI-A by the way. DVI-I is for devices that do both (mostly graphics cards).